# How do I show on my resume that I have stayed with the same group of lawyers for 10 years even though we moved as a group to three different firms?

Tags: resume

How do I show on my resume that I have stayed with the same group of lawyers for 10 years even though we moved as a group to three different firms?

I have stayed with the same "rainmaker" or lead attorney and his group for 10 years but we have moved as a group several times (to start a new firm and then to a client/business partner of that same "rainmaker").  I am not sure if this makes sense but I need to keep my resume to one page and would like a strategy as to how to list the 3 jobs under a more concise heading that would also show that I have continuity in my career despite the different company names. Any advice?

Comment: Overlap with http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18352/showing-promotions-on-cv-when-job-titles-change and http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30621/will-a-job-title-change-in-resume-affect-my-career

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've seen it done in other careers.

One way would be to use 3 lines for the three companies, with a quick note on why these are really the same company, then use the total date range, then describe the work.

For example:

> Firms lead by John Smith, 2004-2014, *title of position*
>
> 2011-2014 - within the office of XYZ - breakout firm lead by John Smith
>
> 2008-2011 - within the office of ABC - partnership between Smith and Wollensky
>
> 2004-2008 - within the office of OPQ - hired by John Smith's group
>
> Position included...

The other thought is - after 10 years, the positions prior to that time should be fairly short and may even be ommitted if they don't provide useful information or indication of your current skills.  I don't know what the standards are for lawyers, but I really don't expect to be too interested in 10 year old technology and projects when I read the resumes of engineers.